# Button call JQuery function who call php file

Tags: php, jquery

```
$(function(){
$('#boutonCreerPlat').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '',
        data: 'string',
        success: $.post( "plat.php", function( data ) {
            $( "#plat" ).append( data );
        }),
        dataType: 'string'
    });
});


<?php
echo '<div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">Créer un plat</label>
        <input name="nomPlat" type="text" class="form-control">
        <select name="prodSelect"></select>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary">Ajouter un produit +</button>
     </div>';
```

The function is OK, echo does 'print' on the web page, but almost everytime, it disappears almost instantly.
Any ideas?

Comment: your question is unclear. What is the relation between jquery code and php code you have given? Please clarify what's the issue, in which code issue occur? What you expected to be happen?

Comment: _“but almost everytime, it disappear almost instantly”_ - most likely because you have an actual form around the whole thing, and you neglected to suppress the default action of a click on such button, which is to submit the form normally – and that either loads a “new” page or the same one again, depending on the form action.

Comment: misorude, thank's, the soluce was a 'return false' in the Jquery function.
now the form don't react each time I click my button

Comment: Can you provide more html so we can see where the data gets appended eg. `<div id="plat" />` and what invokes the call eg. `<button id="boutonCreerPlat" />`?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you doesn't use ajax in the correct way. Try this

```
$('#boutonCreerPlat').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'plat.php',
        data: 'string',
        success: function( data ) {
                   $( "#plat" ).append( data );
                 }
    });
});
```

Comment: The button was inside a form. had to set a return false on the on.click.

Thx Misorude, and all to help me :)

how to set this topic resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ajax which you should try. Hope it will help you.

```
$('#boutonCreerPlat button').click(function(){


        $('#plat').html('');// clear the #plat value first
        $.ajax({
            url: "plat.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'string',
            dataType: 'html'
        })
        .done(function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            $('#plat').html(''); // blank before load.
            $('#plat').html(data); // load here
        })
        .fail(function(){
            $('#plat').html('Something went wrong, Please try again...');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form role="form" action="form.php">
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Date</label>
                    <input type="text" name="date_menu" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Date repas">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Heure</label>
                    <input type="text" name="heure_menu" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Heure repas">
                </div>
                <hr>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="boutonCreerPlat">Ajouter un plat | +</button>
                <div id="plat"></div>
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->

            <div class="box-footer">
                <input style="margin-top:3vh;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
```

Here is the html code you asked twmulloy